# Tag synonym request: [xfce4] -> [xfce]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There is really no need for a separate [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) tag, since virtually any question about [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce) in Ubuntu will pertain to major version 4. Previous versions are not currently supported in Ubuntu. ([They use GTK+ **1**!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfce#Modern_Xfce)) We might get a question about an earlier version on extremely rare occasion, but I don't think this merits a separate tag.

Still, I don't think [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) should be blacklisted. Other desktop environments have tags for their current versions, so [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) should exist for consistency. But (perhaps) unlike for some desktop environments, it shouldn't be a separate tag. People aren't using versions of Xfce prior to 4 these days. At least not often enough to merit a separate tag.

As I write this, there is only one question tagged [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4). There are 196 questions tagged [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce). As far as I can tell, they're all about Xfce 4.

**Therefore, I recommend we make [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) a synonym of [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce).** (I cannot propose the synonym myself, since I don't have a high enough answer score in [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I manually retagged the 4 questions that had the [xfce4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce4) tag with [xfce](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xfce) tag. This question can now be marked as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: Thanks! However, [tag:xfce4] will probably arise again, and I see no reason for it not to be a synonym of [tag:xfce]. (If Xfce 5 comes out some day, we can always change it.)

Comment: Ups, xfce4 came again D:.